# Integrating Google Translate service in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, google, languages, browser-support

Would it be possible to integrate Google Translate as a feature into the text editor of Stack Overflow? It could be stationed alongside the usual formatting tools, requiring a simple click of a button to translate a users question to english, and back their language for answers. Better yet, translation of the entire page depending on your visitors language would also be nifty:
http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/115706042431009629871/GoogleSiteTranslator.xml

I recently noticed a Area51 proposal for a french version of Stack Overflow. A solution like this might cut the need for such a thing out, and bring in even more expert programmers to this database. Of course challenges like imperfect translations might mean we end up roasting in editing-hell, but so far Google Trans seems to work really well, and is still improving.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that machine translation has more difficulty with technical writing that can often have a bit of jargon in it.  Consider that someone might be having trouble importing a library that is in a jar into a project.  Then, you are making use of for loops while doing other things, or is it while loops for doing over things?  And for some reason, that string interning involves a student job?

Comment: @MichaelT Ahhhh...yea...hadn't considered that issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is already built into some browsers (most notably, Chrome). Machine translation is ... subpar. Worse in some languages than others, but could be okay for reading.

Unfortunately, it can't be relied on for allowing folks to ask or answer questions on Stack Overflow when they're not very comfortable with English as if that barrier did not exist.

Even if you account for edits (although fixing bad machine translation can be hard, especially if you can't communicate with the author to get any clarification), there's bound to be a lot of stuff ... please excuse me, I can't help it ... lost in translation.